# Android: SecurityException despite adding permission

Tags: android

I follow the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) to receive location updates from my app. I added the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.myapplication" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, I still get the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: Are you running it in an emulator? If you are, please specify the Android version your emulator is running. It may be M, and if that's the case I know there've been some changes in permission management.

Comment: There are some similar questions. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552170/google-play-services-client-must-have-access-fine-location-permission-to-reques and this: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: @PauloAvelar YES! Yes it is!

Comment: Please check the question linked by oguzhand, it points to another question that talks about Android M. Either way, this could also help: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-permissions-in-android-m--cms-24443.